# Regex to get everything before and after last occurrence of a number

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to construct a regex that will split before and after the last occurrence of a number. I expect to get:

```
"index100.html"         # => ["index", "100", ".html"]
"page.php?id=100"       # => ["page.php?id=", "100", ""]
"page.php?f=5&page=295" # => ['page.php?f=5&page=', 295, '']
```

Here is the regex I came up with:

```
regex = /([^0-9]+|^)(\d+?)([^0-9]+|$)/
```

It works for the first two examples, but not for the last one. I get the result:

```
["page.php?f=", 5, "&page="]
```

How can I modify the regex to make it work the the third case?

Comment: Try this `(.*)(\d+)(.*)`

Comment: The [`(.*)(\d+)(.*)`](http://rubular.com/r/orRN2ecoQk) won't work.

Comment: Why not buddy ? You're right my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You may leverage a `.*` greedy matching, but curb it with a negative lookbehind `(?<!\d)` to make sure you match the whole last chunk of digits:

```
/(.*)(?<!\d)(\d+)(.*)/
 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/KG1DVgdtz6). Optionally, you may add `\A` and `\z` anchors at the start and end.

**Details**:

- `(.*)` - 0 or more characters other than a newline, as many as possible, matching up to the last
- `(?<!\d)(\d+)` - 1+ digits that are NOT preceded with a digit
- `(.*)` - the rest of the line.

To match across newlines, add the `m` modifier after the last regex delimiter.

Comment: Given that the first segment should not be empty, you can make the non-digit the last part of the first segment.

Comment: @sawa: I rely on backtracking here, it should do its job well enough. People usually shout when I start complicating the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Another way without lookbehind.

`((?:\d*\D)*)(\d+)(.*)`

another without lookbehind
(*this is just as fast as using a lookbehind

but if you don't have it, like JS, this works better*)

`(.*(?:\D|^))(\d+)(.*)`

Comment: This assumes that no number except the last one has more than one digit. I don't think that's a safe assumption. How about replacing `?` with `*`?

Comment: These two regexps are not equivalent: the second one requires at least one character before the number, or the number must be at the start of the line. That is why I would not compare performance.

Comment: What do you mean buddy? `\D` can only exist before a `\d` or BOS can only exist. There are no other options ... Performance and regex construct to a negative look behind is identical.

Comment: Also, the 2 regexes in this post are identical except in performance

Answer (score 1):

```
"index100.html"
.partition(/\d+(?=\D*\z)/) # => ["index", "100", ".html"]

"page.php?id=100"
.partition(/\d+(?=\D*\z)/) # => ["page.php?id=", "100", ""]

"page.php?f=5&page=295"
.partition(/\d+(?=\D*\z)/) # => ["page.php?f=5&page=", "295", ""]
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_it(str)
  str.reverse.partition(/\d+/).reverse.map(&:reverse)
end

split_it "index100.html"
  #=> ["index", "100", ".html"]
split_it "page.php?id=100"
  #=> ["page.php?id=", "100", ""]
split_it "page.php?f=5&page=295"
  #=> ['page.php?f=5&page=', 295, '']
```

The steps for

```
str = "page.php?f=5&page=295"
```

are as follows:

```
s = str.reverse
  #=> "592=egap&5=f?php.egap" 
a = s.partition(/\d+/)
  #=> ["", "592", "=egap&5=f?php.egap"] 
b = a.reverse
  #=> ["=egap&5=f?php.egap", "592", ""] 
b.map(&:reverse)
  #=> ["page.php?f=5&page=", "295", ""]
```